# How to get a list of users who like a current wordpress post

Tags: php

I am using this [post like system](https://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/wordpress-post-like-system/) in my WordPress theme and its working fine. My WordPress theme is only for registered user, i mean only registered user can read my post. Now want to display all users list who liked the post in single page under any specific div.

can someone help me with a solution?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code samples in the article `_user_liked` post meta should hold all the user ids of those who liked it. Something like this should be able to solve it for you

```
<?php
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$users_liked = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_user_liked', true );

if ( '' !== $users_liked && ! empty( $users_liked ) ) {
  ?>
  <ul>
  <?php foreach ( array_values( $users_liked ) as $user_id ) : 
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    if ( false === $user ) {
      continue;
    }
    ?>
    <li><?php echo $user->user_login; ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: I try this but getting error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Comment: @gulrathod Yes, my bad. Try the updated code

Comment: thank you :) its working, i am getting user name list who like a current post. i am getting only user name, can you please tell me if i want user name with profile link or you can say author link, how can i get ???